# Как нарисовать маленькие оси в углу экрана на opengl?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

На данный момент у меня есть сцена выглядит вот так, хочу нарисовать оси в углу экрана, которые бы вращались вместе с камерой, не особо понимаю, как это сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может есть у кого пример, либо информация, куда копать. Оси всегда в углу экрана, как в редакторах, просто чтобы знать направления координатных осей. Рисую я с помощью VAO, VBO и.т.п, вроде это современный OpenGL без всех этих glBegin и glEnd.

Comment: оси - это три отрезка или три прямоугольника (очень длинных). еще нужно три конуса/пирамиды. Если умеете рисовать треугольник, то нарисовать пирамиду не должно быть проблем - просто аккуратно посчитать координаты и применить матрицы вида/переноса. А вот с линиями - нет проблем - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486291/how-to-draw-line-in-opengl (там как раз решается Ваша проблема)

Answer (score 0):

По идее:

1. Нарисовать сцену
2. Если у вас вращение только у объекта - Выставить матрицу модели без переноса (только вращение), матрицы вида и проекции (орто, или перспективную, как больше нравится)
   Если у вас вращение через камеру сделано - матрица модели берется единичная, а матрица вида - только вращение (если LookAt, то в единичной сфере) и матрицу проекции (орто, или перспективную, как больше нравится)
3. Выставляете viewport на область в углу экрана
4. Рисуете оси - они будут поверх текущей картинки
5. И только теперь SwapBuffers

Comment: ох ох. я как раз решал недавно вот почти такой же вопрос. И Ваш ответ в 4 пункте как раз прячет весь ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim тут уж зависит от точности вопроса - нарисовать 3 линии со стрелками единичного размера, как мне кажется, вообще тривиально. Вы можете дополнить?

Comment: Тривиально, если знаешь как. Треугольники и кубы - так это в любом туториале. А как линию нарисовать - юлят.

Comment: @KoVadim я вот так сейчас рисую `glLineWidth(aLineWidth); glDrawArrays(GL_LINES_STRIP, 0, Length(aArray));`, но может быть это хорошая тема для нового вопроса ;-)